# Long line of code in comments breaks UI

Tags: bug

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13566720/2510678) there is [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566552/easiest-way-to-convert-month-name-to-month-number-in-js-jan-01/13566720#comment18589222_13566720) containing a very long code fragment, the result is this:

[image]

Using chrome (38.0.2125.122 m)

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior in Firefox 33.1.

Comment: Reproduced in Safari, iPad Air, iOS 7.

Comment: The problem is not with a "long line of code", but with a very "long *word*" (ie: without space)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It's not a duplicate, just the same bug caused by a different array of characters.

Comment: @cybermonkey Hence "possible duplicate" - the underlying issue is the same.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Point taken.

Comment: I don't agree that this question is a duplicate, as the 'duplicate' has no answers. Going by the Stack Exchange rules, this question can't technically be classified as a dupe at the moment.