# Long code line breaks out of comment

Tags: bug, comments

Just ran across this phenomenon, where a long line of `formatted code` breaks out of the right bounds of the comment:

[image: Long line of formatted code breaks out of bounds of comment under a post]

Apparently this has been observed in the (distant) past: [Long line of code in comments breaks UI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276895/long-line-of-code-in-comments-breaks-ui).

[Link to the comment in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63854737/traversing-tree-by-level#comment112917203_63854737).

Using Chrome 85.0.4183.102 on Windows 10.

Comment: No repro in FF on Win10. Repro in Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit) Win10.

Comment: Can't reproduce in Firefox, Safari, or Chrome on macOS.

Comment: Not seeing it in FF or Edge personally either.

Comment: @zcoop98 I see it in Chrome, windows 10.

Comment: [Reproducible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxiHD.png) in Opera on Windows 10. Here it's on it's way into Arqade.

Comment: Also remind the OP that *comments* are not meant for, nor particularly suited, any more code than a single statement.